# write to code without prefix table name

Tags: 7, database

I work on D7, My Sql database name is `dbdrupal7` and all table prefix with **abc** (abc_block, abc_node, ...), website work fine. I create a custom table without prefix **abc** (custom). I create a module and write to custom code.

```
$query = db_select('custom', 'c'); 

$query->fields('c');

$results = $query->execute();
```

...

...

Show "unexpected Error" when browse.

I not want to change table name **custom** to **abc_custom** in database.

My question is how write correct code `db_select('custom', 'c');` without prefix.

Comment: This question seems very similar to this one: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/150728/db-update-without-table-prefix-on-custom-table . Might that solution work for you?

Answer (score 3):

That behaviour is hard-coded with a `SelectQuery`; the prefix will apply to all tables, without exception, and there's no mechanism in place to override it. It happens in [`SelectQuery::__toString()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3A__toString/7) if you're interested.

If you want to change that, you'll need to subclass `SelectQuery`, add a mechanism to let the class know which tables should/shouldn't be prefixed, and override the `__toString()` method to take that into account. Then you'll need your own version of `db_select()`, which uses your new custom version of the class.

All that's probably not worth the effort given that you can run an arbitrary SQL string with `db_query()`. For example, the following won't attempt to prefix `custom`:

```
db_query('SELECT * FROM custom c')
```

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way would be to treat the other tables as non-drupal databases, because they aren't (Otherwise they would be prefixed). You can see how to do this here:

[How to connect to multiple databases within Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/18429)